# Tim thumb in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want do same working like php timthumb do in ror I tried gems but not found result as I want.
Images are taking much time to load.

for example code in php :

Can check what I required on :

http://www.darrenhoyt.com/demo/timthumb/

I want same way in ror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [minimagick gem](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) to compress image size and quality.

For example:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(YOUR_IMAGE)
image.resize "130x100"  ## The thumbnail size
image.write(YOUR_THUMB)
```

Comment: Oh, can you tell me how you want to do a resize operation? If you want to resize a file from a url,you can call `image = MiniMagick::Image.open('http://XXX....jpg')` then resize it and store to local storage.

Comment: after re size I saved my images in tmp folder how can I access them "http://localhost:3000/tmp/1420725482.png" like these can you say how can I do these?

Comment: You can write the resize image to your rails public folder `YOUR_RAILS_APP/public/tmp` with `image.write("#{Rails.root}/public/tmp/THUMB_XXX.jpg")`,then run rails server, and access it `http://localhost:3000/tmp/THUMB_XXX.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

When you upload an imagine you want to have different sized versions that have been processed from the original.

Carrier wave to upload the image and resize it
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

You can resize as documented here: [Carrier Wave - Versions](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#create-versions-from-existing-versions)

To be more precise here are associated tutorials for what you want using carrierwave and various libs for the conversions: [Image Dimensions](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Get-image-dimensions)

You can even change the image type to keep a standard and do more image processing with libraries. Here is how: [Image Processing](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/Efficiently-converting-image-formats)

Comment: Thanks, But I cannot resize image same so many copy of one image as I am using AWS S3.

Comment: it would have worked not sure why you could not follow the documentation @MiteshSharma